# How to make my button change once clicked to carry out a different function?

Tags: javascript, html, button, colors

At the moment I have two buttons, "Green" and "Red". Once "Green" is clicked the text in the div (red as default) goes green. And when the "Red" button is clicked the text goes red. These are two separately working buttons that carry out the function I want.

But I want there to be just one button. The Default button will be called "Green", once clicked it will change the font of the div to green and the button will change name to "Red". Once "Red" is clicked it will turn the font back to red and the button back to "Green".

How do I go about this using javascript? JQuery won't be much help to me as I am trying to master javascript at the moment.

Here is my current html with my two working buttons:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clock3.css">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<title> Clock Part III </title>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = time;

function time () {

var today = new Date();
var hours = today.getHours();
var minutes = today.getMinutes(); 
var seconds = today.getSeconds();

if (hours < 10)
            hours = "0" + hours
if (minutes < 10)
            minutes = "0" + minutes
if (seconds < 10)
           seconds = "0" + seconds 

times = hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = times;

setTimeout(time, 1000);

}

 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);




 </script>





</head>

<body>

<button type="button" id="green" onclick = 'document.getElementById("timer").style.color = ("#088A08");'>Green</button>
<button type="button" id="red" onclick = 'document.getElementById("timer").style.color =      ("#FF0000");'>Red</button>

<h1> Clock </h1>

<div id="timer"></div>

</body>


</html>
```

Thanks in advance!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set a flag like

```
var isGreen = true;
```

and create a function

```
function colorControl (el){ 
  if(isGreen){
    document.getElementById("timer").style.color = ("#088A08");
    isGreen= false;
    el.innerHTML = "RED";
    return;
   }
  document.getElementById("timer").style.color = ("#FF0000");
  isGreen = true;

 el.innerHTML = "Green";
}
```

And your button like that:

```
<button type="button" id="green" onclick ="colorControl(this)">Green</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @AlexisPeters This works, it changes my font color with one button. But how can I make the button change to the name "Red" when the text goes green?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `click` event listener using JavaScript instead of HTML.

Within the listener, check the button's `textContent` property.  With it, you can set the `timer` color and change the button's text:

```
var button  = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click',function() {
  var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
  if(this.textContent === 'Red') {
    timer.style.color= '#ff0000';
    this.textContent= 'Green';
  }
  else {
    timer.style.color= '#088a08';    
    this.textContent= 'Red';
  }
});
```

```js
function time () {
  var today = new Date();
  var hours = today.getHours();
  var minutes = today.getMinutes(); 
  var seconds = today.getSeconds();

  if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours
  if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes
  if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds 

  times = hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = times;
  setTimeout(time, 1000);
}

var button  = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click',function() {
  var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
  if(this.textContent === 'Red') {
    timer.style.color= '#ff0000';
    this.textContent= 'Green';
  }
  else {
    timer.style.color= '#088a08';    
    this.textContent= 'Red';
  }
});

time();
```

```css
#timer {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>

<button id="button">Green</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I gave this a try but the button didn't change the div text color or change the button title

Comment: Delete one of your buttons, change the id of the other button to "button," and delete its `onclick` handler.  If you click `Show code snippet`, you'll see how I changed your HTML as well as your JavaScreipt.

Answer (score 0):

```
  
 Green 
            function changeColor(self)
            {
                if(self.innerHTML == "Green")
                {
                    document.getElementById("timer").style.color = "#088A08";
                    self.innerHTML = "Red";
                }
                else if(self.innerHTML == "Red")
                {
                    document.getElementById("timer").style.color = "#FF0000";
                    self.innerHTML = "Green";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a toggle() function...

```
function toggle () {

    var color;

    if (document.getElementById('button').style.color == "green") {
        color = "red";
    } else {
        color = "green";
    }

    document.getElementById('button').style.color = color;
    document.getElementById("timer").style.color = color;
}
```

Set the button and timer default color with...

```
...style="color:green;"...
```